# Alsa not working at all

Tags: command-line, sound, 15.04, alsa

So I had some issues with my microphone not working for some time, and I tried something , and now i can;t hear anything either. There is no sound bar at the top right of the screen. when i try to do "alsamixer" in the terminal it tells me "cannot open mixer: No such file or directory". it did that before all sound broke too though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall pulse audio and alsa.

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio
sudo apt-get remove alsa-base
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

After doing that if that just to make sure everything restarts run this command:

```
sudo pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```